# Best Wiki for Mobile Users

Tags: iphone, wiki, mobile-website

Most wiki software I've presents lots of "features" on their pages.  This is fine for desktop users, but is annoying when using an iPhone or other mobile device.  
I'd prefer pages that just had the content, along with maybe an Edit button and a Search button.  The editors are also often too fancy for mobile users; a simple multi-line edit field would be better for mobile users than a bunch of formatting controls.

What is a good wiki package for mobile users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W2 by Steven Frank (of Panic, makers of Transmit) is awesome. 
It's totally stripped down for iPhone--just the essentials. 
It supports markdown and basic Wiki-style formatting. 
https://github.com/panicsteve/w2wiki

That page has a link to a demo site.

Answer (score 2):

I find the wiki in Fogbugz to be very good using it with the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to override the mediawiki skins with your own. You could remove whatever you want to without much of a problem.